# Getting error while running heroku run python manage.py migrate

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am a beginner in heroku and django and I am trying to create an application. While I was importing my database to heroku by running command -

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

I get an error saying -

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 373, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 417, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 87, in wrapped
    saved_locale = translation.get_language()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 182, in get_language
    return _trans.get_language()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    if settings.USE_I18N:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 84, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 71, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 179, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pp'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/app/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 425, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 386, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 208, in close_all
    for alias in self:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 73, in __iter__
    return iter(self.settings)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 45, in settings
    self._settings = self.configure_settings(self._settings)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 144, in configure_settings
    databases = super().configure_settings(databases)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 50, in configure_settings
    settings = getattr(django_settings, self.settings_name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 84, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 71, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 179, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pp'
```

What should I do to successfully import my database to heroku and get it working? Please let me know if I need to add any of my files on here.

This is my directory layout in visual studio code -

[Django directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z51JD.png)

Comment: It may be that the module 'pp' represents a package you have installed in your development environment, but not in your production environment.  My guess is this is the problem, and it may have nothing to do with your database.

Comment: But I haven't installed any module named 'pp'. 'pp' is the name of the folder which contains the django files

Comment: Does the migration work in your local environment?  Does the production environment use the same file structure?  What do you mean by 'django files'?  Your source directory for apps?  It's hard to tell what the issue is without more information.

Comment: Yes, the django app runs properly in the local environment. (Which is what I think you mean by migration in local environment). By django files I mean the directory which holds all the files to run the application ( eg. settings.py, urls.py, etc.)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your directory layout. I suspect it is not what Heroku is expecting.

Comment: I just did that

Comment: Would really appreciate your help!